# PHP, assigning a value to a variable by reference

Tags: php

a friend asked me to analyze the output of the following simple lines.
I defined a variable **x** that has the string *PHP*, and a table called ***a*** which is a reference to ***x***, so any changes to one of them will affect the other. First, I assigned the value *"Mysql"* to the first element of ***a***, the value of ***x*** changed too.
But in the second affectation, when the second element of the table ***a*** got the value *"test"*, the value of the variable ***x*** didn't change, any explanation?

```
<?php
    $x = "PHP";

    $a[] = &$x;
    $a[0] = "MySql";
    
    echo $a[0]; // Output: MySql
    echo $x;   // Output: MySql

    $a[1] = "test";
    echo $a[1]; // Output: test
    echo $x; // Output: MySql
    // why last output is mySql and not test?
?>
```

Comment: When you do `$a[] = &$x;` you're creating an array `$a` and pushing the variable `&$x` to the array (at index 0). It's essentially the same as`$a = []; $a[0] = &$x;`. So `$a[1]` is never pointing to `&$x`. Did you mean to do `$a = &$x;`? In which case, `$a` would be a string referencing the same value as `$x`.

Comment: `$x` is only referenced/associated/linked to `$a[0]` not to `$a[1]`. If you repeat the test with `$a[0] = 'test';` then you will see the `$x` reference also changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to `$x` is never in `$a[1]`. It is only in `$a[0]` and therefore won't change when you assign 'test' to `$a[1]`.

`$a[] = &$x;` is just adding `&$x` to the end of the array `$a`. `$a` at that point in your code is empty, so you are assigning `&$x` to the first index of `$a` (`$a[0]`)